# React beautiful DND - I get "Unable to find draggable with id: task-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

In the following code, I have two columns. One column has all the tasks. The other column has a group of selected tasks. So, my expectation is that, when a user drags and drops a task from the total tasks column to the selected tasks column, the task should still be there in total tasks column. When the tasks are there in the selected tasks column, there will be a button visible to delete the tasks from selected tasks column. When I click this button, the task gets removed from the selected tasks column. But I am not able to drag it again from the total tasks column. I am getting the following error:

Unable to find draggable with id: task-2

Request you guys to take a look and tell me what's the mistake I am doing

Please find the link for the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-waterfall-wdyc5?file=/src/task.jsx

Also this is my code:

**App.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import '@atlaskit/css-reset';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import initialData from './initial-data';
import Column from './column';

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

class App extends React.Component {
    state = initialData;

  onDragStart = start => {
    const homeIndex = this.state.columnOrder.indexOf(start.source.droppableId);

    this.setState({
      homeIndex,
    });
  };

  onDragEnd = result => {
    this.setState({
      homeIndex: null,
    });

    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;

    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    const home = this.state.columns[source.droppableId];
    const foreign = this.state.columns[destination.droppableId];

    if (home === foreign) {
      const newTaskIds = Array.from(home.taskIds);
      newTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
      newTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);

      const newHome = {
        ...home,
        taskIds: newTaskIds,
      };

      const newState = {
        ...this.state,
        columns: {
          ...this.state.columns,
          [newHome.id]: newHome,
        },
      };

      this.setState(newState);
      return;
    }

    const foreignTaskIds = Array.from(foreign.taskIds);
    foreignTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);
    const newForeign = {
      ...foreign,
      taskIds: foreignTaskIds,
    };

    const newState = {
      ...this.state,
      columns: {
        ...this.state.columns,
        [newForeign.id]: newForeign,
      },
    };
    this.setState(newState);
  };

  deleteHandler = (taskId) => {
        
        console.warn("I am going to delete: " + taskId);
        var columnId = 'column-2';
        
        const column = this.state.columns[columnId];
        const columnTaskIds = Array.from(column.taskIds);
        columnTaskIds.splice(columnTaskIds.indexOf(taskId), 1);
        const newcolumn = {
        ...column,
        taskIds: columnTaskIds,
        };
        var newState = null;
        newState = {
            ...this.state,
      columns: {
        ...this.state.columns,
              [newcolumn.id]: newcolumn
      }
        };
        this.setState(newState);
        console.log(newState);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <DragDropContext
        onDragStart={this.onDragStart}
        onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}
      >
        <Container>
          {this.state.columnOrder.map((columnId, index) => {
            const column = this.state.columns[columnId];
            const tasks = column.taskIds.map(
              taskId => this.state.tasks[taskId],
            );

            const isDropDisabled = index < this.state.homeIndex;

            return (
              <Column
                key={column.id}
                column={column}
                tasks={tasks}
                isDropDisabled={isDropDisabled}
                deleteHandler={this.deleteHandler}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Container>
      </DragDropContext>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

**column.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import Task from './task';

const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 220px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
const Title = styled.h3`
  padding: 8px;
`;
const TaskList = styled.div`
  padding: 8px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  background-color: ${props => (props.isDraggingOver ? 'skyblue' : 'white')};
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
`;

export default class Column extends React.Component {
  isSelectedTasksColumn = this.props.column.id === 'column-2';
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>{this.props.column.title}</Title>
        <Droppable
          droppableId={this.props.column.id}
          isDropDisabled={this.props.isDropDisabled}
        >
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <TaskList
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
            >
              {this.props.tasks.map((task, index) => (
                <Task key={task.id} task={task} index={index} isSelectedTasksColumn={this.isSelectedTasksColumn} deleteHandler={this.props.deleteHandler}/>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </TaskList>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**task.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Container = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: ${props =>
    props.isDragDisabled
      ? 'lightgrey'
      : props.isDragging
        ? 'lightgreen'
        : 'white'};
`;

const DeleteButton = styled.button`
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    border: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: ${props => props.isSelectedTasksColumn ? "inline" : "none"};
    float: right;
`;

const DisplayValue = styled.p`
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
`;

export default class Task extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const isDragDisabled = false;
    return (
      <Draggable
        draggableId={this.props.task.id}
        index={this.props.index}
        isDragDisabled={isDragDisabled}
      >
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <Container
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
            isDragDisabled={isDragDisabled}
          >
            <DisplayValue>{this.props.task.content}</DisplayValue>
            <DeleteButton isSelectedTasksColumn = {this.props.isSelectedTasksColumn}
              onClick={() => this.props.deleteHandler(this.props.task.id)}>
              &#x2716;
            </DeleteButton>
          </Container>
        )}
      </Draggable>
    );
  }
}
```

**initial-data.js:**

```
const initialData = {
  tasks: {
    'task-1': { id: 'task-1', content: 'Task 1' },
    'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'Task 2' },
    'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'Task 3' },
    'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'Task 4' },
  },
  columns: {
    'column-1': {
      id: 'column-1',
      title: 'All tasks',
      taskIds: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4'],
    },
    'column-2': {
      id: 'column-2',
      title: 'Selected tasks',
      taskIds: [],
    }
  },
  // Facilitate reordering of the columns
  columnOrder: ['column-1', 'column-2'],
};

export default initialData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing React.StrictMode could help
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html